# Bash split string on delimiter, assign segments to array

Tags: bash

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I would like to transform a PATH-like environment variable that *may* contain space-separated elements into an `array`, making *sure* elements bearing spaces do not cause word-splitting, appearing as "multiple elements".

---

Let `PATH_VARIABLE` be the variable in question.

Let `un:dodecaedro:per:tirare:per:i danni` be the content of the variable.

*It is* **intended** *for the desired* `array` _to have `6` elements, not `7`.

```
0) un
1) dodecaedro
2) per
3) tirare
4) per
5) i danni
```

The "tricky" entry may be the space-separated value: `i danni`.

I am looking for the absolute *most elegant* **and** correct way to achieve this.

Limitation: it must work with my [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version: `v3.2.48(1)-release`

---

In [python](/questions/tagged/python) this is done just *beautifully* as so:

```
>>> v='un:dodecaedro:per:tirare:per:i danni'
>>> len(v.split(':'))
6
```

Works. Shows what I am looking for.

---

What's the best way to do this in our beloved [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)?

Can you specifically improve on my attempt `4`?

#### Here my attempts

---

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH_VARIABLE='un:dodecaedro:per:tirare:per:i danni'

# WRONG
a1=($(echo $PATH_VARIABLE | tr ':' '\n'))

# WRONG
a2=($(
  while read path_component; do
  echo "$path_component"
  done < <(echo "$PATH_VARIABLE" | tr ':' '\n')
))

# WORKS, it is elegant.. but I have no bash 4!
# readarray -t a3 < <(echo "$PATH_VARIABLE" | tr ':' '\n')

# WORKS, but it looks "clunky" to me :(
i=0
while read line; do
  a4[i++]=$line
done < <(echo "$PATH_VARIABLE" | tr ':' '\n')

n=${#a4[@]}
for ((i=0; i < n; i++)); do
  printf '%2d) %s\n' "$i" "${a4[i]}"
done
```

---

#### My environment

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) v3.2.48(1)-release

[osx](/questions/tagged/osx) OS X v10.8.3 (build 12D78)

---

Comment: 3.2.48-1 — Apple, Mac OS X?  My shell reports 3.2.48(1) with parentheses instead of a dash, so maybe not.  Why don't the first two options work for you?  They both worked for me (and I didn't expect the second to work because I was under the illusion that my bash didn't support process substitution `<(...)` — maybe the `sh` version doesn't but the `bash` version does... _yes: `sh` does not and `bash` does have process substitution_).

Comment: Indeed, Mac OS X "the Cougar". Intellectual slavery. Instrument of subjugation. Anyway, `a1` and `a2` split to `7` elements, not `6`.. right?

Comment: Ah...point out such subtleties so people know why the obvious-seeming answer isn't the one you want.

Comment: I added a "My environment" section! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f() {
  local IFS=:
  local foo
  set -f # Disable glob expansion
  foo=( $@ ) # Deliberately unquoted 
  set +f
  printf '%d\n' "${#foo[@]}"
  printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"
}

f 'un:dodecaedro:per:tirare:per:i danni'
6
un
dodecaedro
per
tirare
per
i danni
```

Modifying Jim McNamara's answer, you could just reset IFS:

```
oIFS="$IFS"
foo='un:dodecaedro:per:tirare:per:i danni'
IFS=: arr=( $foo )
IFS="$oIFS"
```

I prefer the function scope because it protects IFS changes from bleeding into the global scope without requiring special care to reset it.

### Edits and explanations:

As a matter of clarification: In the second example, the IFS setting *does* change the global variable. The salient difference between this:

```
IFS=: arr=( $foo )
```

and this:

```
IFS=: read -a arr <<< "$foo"
```

is that the former is two variable assignments and no commands, and the latter is *a simple command* (see *simple command* in `man (1) bash`.)

#### Demonstration:

```
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
3.2.48(1)-release
$ echo "$IFS"


$ foo='un:dodecaedro:per:tirare:per:i danni'
$ IFS=: read -a arr <<< "$foo"
$ echo "${#arr[@]}"
6
$ echo "$IFS"


$ IFS=: arr1=( $foo )
$ echo "${#arr1[@]}"
6
$ echo "$IFS"
:
```

Comment: This line works for me: `IFS=: foo=( $1 )`. `6` elements. No `;` before the assignment. Change it to `foo=( $1 )` -> `2` elements. Can you try/report back result?

Comment: `IFS=: foo=($1)` "works", but it's messy without the function scope, because it spills the value of IFS into the global scope. With the function controlling the scope, however, you don't need to put the things on one line.

Comment: Does not on my systems. Please check and let us know.. (I tried: GNU/Linux (kernel 3.5.0-25-generic) Ubuntu 12.10 `bash` v4.2.37(1)-release too). `IFS` does not _"spill"_ beyond the one statement in which it is specified before the assignment..

Comment: @Robottinosino Does not what? Please clarify what you're asking for.

Comment: I contend that what you wrote could be written more concisely: `IFS=: foo=( $1 )`. `IFS`, I say, does not get set globally by prefixing it to the array assignment. I also say there are no other adverse effects of being more "concise" that way. Used within a function or not.

Comment: This tiny detail aside, which I encourage you to verify, your solution is so elegant that I'd call it "pure" and "perfect". I could have not had a better answer. Thanks a Million for that.

Comment: Nice edit. I keep liking this input of yours more. Love the elegance of the here string and love the fact that, after all, bash 3 _does_ have `read -a`, if not `readarray`.

Comment: Anyay, I learned a TON from your post, I don't really know what else to say that won't sound cheesy to thank you even more!

Comment: This is wrong. Never use unquoted expansions for splitting values. At the very least, you would have to toggle `set -f`, but this is still not a good approach. Won't downvote since the correct answer is at least included, though the explanation of the differences is very incomplete.

Comment: @ormaaj Yes, I usually forget to disable glob expansions, so edited. But having done so, why is it *still not a good approach*?

Comment: Globbing and controlling the `IFS` and `set -f` state for the duration of whatever you're doing are the most serious problems. All the usual pitfalls of things like iterating over lines using `for x in $(<file)` also apply -- any adjacent IFS members will be dropped and can't be preserved. If all that is ok, sure you can do it this way, it's just incredibly stupid. Unquoted expansions are misused by basically everyone, and are the source of the majority of scripting errors (often dangerous, security-related ones). Not a good thing to promote.

Comment: ...Additionally, attempting to solve it with a function introduces a new problem because now you have to create an abstraction for indirect array assignment. Outputting a newline-delimited stream doesn't really solve anything. You just implemented a really hilarious `tr : '\n'`.

Answer (score 7):

```
# Right. Add -d '' if PATH members may contain newlines.
IFS=: read -ra myPath <<<"$PATH"

# Wrong!
IFS=: myPath=($PATH)

# Wrong!
IFS=:
for x in $PATH; do ...

# How to do it wrong right...
# Works around some but not all word split problems
# For portability, some extra wrappers are needed and it's even harder.
function stupidSplit {
    if [[ -z $3 ]]; then
        return 1
    elif [[ $- != *f* ]]; then
        trap 'trap RETURN; set +f' RETURN
        set -f
    fi
    IFS=$3 command eval "${1}=(\$${2})"
}

function main {
    typeset -a myPath
    if ! stupidSplit myPath PATH :; then
        echo "Don't pass stupid stuff to stupidSplit" >&2
        return 1
    fi
}

main
```

Rule #1: Don't cram a compound data structure into a string or stream unless there's no alternative. `PATH` is one case where you have to deal with it.

Rule #2: Avoid word / field splitting at all costs. There are almost no legitimate reasons to apply word splitting on the value of a parameter in non-minimalist shells such as Bash. Almost all beginner pitfalls can be avoided by just never word splitting with IFS. Always quote.

Comment: Awesome. Why is this at the bottom? Good thing I kept scrolling... I knew an elegant one-liner exists for this task. Like for most of the tasks in the shell.

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

```
$ foo='1:2 3:4 5:6'
$ IFS=':'; arr=($foo)
$ echo "${arr[0]}"
1
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
2 3
$ echo "${arr[2]}"
4 5
$ echo "${arr[3]}"
6
```

Oh well - took me too long to format an answer... +1 @kojiro.