# Bash script to find the path of an executable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

EDIT: I KNOW THIS IS REDUNDANT, IT IS HOMEWORK, I HAVE WRITTEN MY OWN CODE AND NEED HELP TROUBLESHOOTING>

As stated, I must write a BASH script to determine whether an executable file is in the users path.

such that if you type
    ./findcmd ping it returns /bin/ping

I have some code written, But it does not properly work and I hope someone can help me troubleshoot. When I type ./findcmd ping it just returns my file does not exist.(with any other file I try as well that I know exists.)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Invoke as ./findcmd command
#
# Check for argument
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
 then
    echo 'useage: ./findcmd command'
    exit 1
fi
#
# Check for one argument
if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]
 then
     pathlist=`echo $PATH | tr ':' ' '`
     for d in $pathlist;
          do
             if [[ ! -d $d || ! -x $d || ! -r $d ]]
               then
                   echo 'You do not have read end execute
                          permissions!'
                   exit 2
              fi
              if [[ $(find $d -name $1 -print | wc -l) -ne 0 ]]
                   then
                         echo 'The file does not exist in the PATH!'
                          exit 0

             fi
        done
fi

exit 0
#
#
```

Comment: is not `whereis` what you are looking for ?

Comment: There might be other problems too, but one is in: `pathlist=\`echo $PATH | tr ':' ' '\``.  You want to create an array here: `pathlist=($(echo $PATH | tr ':' ' '))`

Comment: When you discover a path where you don't have rx permissions, why stop with `exit 2`?  It would be better to ignore the bad paths completely and continue the loop to find one that works (if any).

Comment: Basically, your tests are almost the opposite of what they should be.... you want to stop when you find a path that works, otherwise keep going until you run out.

Comment: What happens if you eliminate the rx test for now, the first `if/fi` block, completely, and invert the second test, i.e. exit when find succeeds ?

Comment: @Michael So what do you think of my suggestion?

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/type.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use a bash array, `tr`'ing the `':'` with `' '` will work just fine in a for loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Invoke as ./findcmd command
#
# Check for argument
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
 then
    echo 'usage: ./findcmd command'
    exit 1
fi

f=$1

# No need to check the $# again, there's at least one arg and other will be ignored..
# Otherwise you can wrap this in a loop and keep shift'ing args and checking one by one
pathlist=`echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`
for d in $pathlist;
    do
      #echo command is your friend
      #echo "Checking for $f in $d"
      path="$d/$f"
      if [[ -f "$path" && -x "$path" ]]; then
         # PATH is not recursive, therefore no need to use find command
         # Simply checking that the file exists and is executable should be enough
         echo "Found $f at '$path'"
         # Note the same filename may be present farther down the PATH 
         # Once the first executable is found, exit
         exit 0
      fi
done

# Getting here means file was not found
echo "$f could not be found"
exit 1
```

Here are the results:

```
rbanikaz@lightsaber:~$ ./which.sh grep
Found grep at '/usr/bin/grep'
rbanikaz@lightsaber:~$ ./which.sh foo
foo could not be found
rbanikaz@lightsaber:~$
```

Comment: This will not work if any of the directories in `$PATH` has a whitespace in it.

Comment: sure, changed it to `tr ':' '\n'` , which also works and handles spaces in directories

Comment: fyi, directories are allowed to have \n characters as well (pretty much anything but '/' for that matter).  The proper way would be to temporarily set OLDIFS="$IFS" IFS=":" ... code ... IFS="$OLDIFS"

Comment: +1, but @technosaurus is correct: use `IFS=':'` (and restore it later)  - that way you don't even need the `tr` command. Also, I suggest using `>&2` to redirect the error messages to _stderr_.

Answer (score -1):

The [which command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_which.htm) already does this...

Techinically this is a solution...

```
#!/bin/bash
which $1
```

I probably wouldn't submit it for as assignment though...

### Update

Messing around a bit and I think the following will code will get your past your current bug:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Invoke as ./findcmd command
#
# Check for argument
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
 then
    echo 'useage: ./findcmd command'
    exit 1
fi
#
# Check for one argument
if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]
 then
     d=$1
     pathlist=($(echo $PATH | tr ':' ' '))
     echo $pathlist

     i=0
    while read line; do
      a4[i++]=$line
    done < <(echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n')

    n=${#a4[@]}
    for ((i=0; i < n; i++)); do
       if [[ ! -d $d || ! -x $d || ! -r $d ]]
       then
          echo 'You do not have read end execute
                          permissions!'
          exit 2
       fi
       if [[ $(find $d -name $1 -print | wc -l) -ne 0 ]]
       then
          echo 'The file does not exist in the PATH!'
          exit 0

       fi
    done
fi

exit 0
#
#
```

Pretty much, it uses a solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777996/bash-split-string-on-delimiter-assign-segments-to-array) to split the $PATH variable into an array and then loops through it, applying the logic you had inside your while statement.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: By not reinventing the wheel.  If this is homework, professor should be more creative in the assignments...

Comment: It is homework, sorry if it is redundant, but I would just like some help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @Paul That's what comments are for.  And it's not a case wherein one doesn't have commenting privileges.

Comment: `which ping` returns `/bin/ping` really. But is @Michael 's question a home work for `write a replacement of which command`?

Comment: @NSjonas The question doesn't ask you to __do__ the homework.  It posts a code snippet that is not working.  You are not obliged to post an answer.

Comment: @devnull sarcasm doesn't reflect well in text.  The fact that it was homework was not made clear in the original question, and I was just giving him a hard time. I updated my answer to provide a solution... Its a not a great solution, and you reserve the right to downvote it.

Comment: @NSjonas There was no sarcasm or pun intended.  The comment clearly said that _there is no obligation to post an answer_ implying that if you cannot help, don't post an answer.  Nevertheless, it's a matter of time that your post would get deleted by itself.

Comment: @devnull I've provided way more of a solution than you have...  You're obviously a competent bash programmer, I'm sure you code have answered this question in the time it took you to write all these comments. At least I'm trying to be helpful...

Comment: @NSjonas Good.  Downvote reversed.  It'd be nice to tell the OP about the problems rather than simply posting the _fixed code_.  (The choice is yours, however.)

Comment: What is `d`? Where is `d` set?

Comment: @devnull tried that.  I think Michael stepped away.

Comment: @Paul I'm assuming dev is suppose to be the command were looking for?  I updated my code to reflect it as so.  I'm tempted to finish this solution just to help improve my own BASH skills but I think this should get him past the bug.

Comment: This script doesn't work.  Testing on Ubuntu 13.10, `./findcmd ping` yields `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm` newline `You do not have read end execute permissions!`  but `which ping` yields `/bin/ping`

Comment: @NSjonas actually I think d was supposed to be a directory name.  The final `for` loop is missing the step of iterating over the directories. Looking carefully, sure there is a loop and `i` changes, but `i` is never used to extract a directory to test from the array. I would think that was the purpose of `d` in that last loop.  I also think the if blocks are incorrect, see my comments attached to the OP's question.